# Do SAP PI (Process integration) needs a SFDC connector at it's end?

Tags: integration, sap

We have the need to integrate SFDC with SAP ECC & SAP BW. The client has SAP PI as the middleware. Do they need to purchase a SFDC connector at SAP PI end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of custom SFDC Adapter until someone wants additional features. SAP PI's SOAP Adapter is suffice for integrating Salesforce